# How to call a public method as static?

Tags: php

I want to use my own library that trace all the activity that happean in the system. Now instead of include this library in each system file I want create one file and include this library called `trace`. Let me show an example:

```
<?php

    class Trace
    {
         public function __construct()
         {
             //Some stuff.
         }

         public function info()
         {
           // write an info text on the log txt file.
         }

    }
```

The code above explain essentially what the `trace` library do in the system, essentially write some thing on a txt file. Anyway, I want create a singleton class that extends all method of `Trace` as static, so I can call the method of `trace` in the file that extends it (sorry for the word around), something like:

```
<?php

      include "trace.php";

      class Test 
      {

      private $_trace;

      public function __construct()
      {
           //Create a new instance here?
           $this->_trace = new Trace();
      }

      public static function info()
      {
          $this->_trace->info() //I can't call $this in static method, this is the main problem
      }
      } //end class
```

How you can see I can't do this 'cause `$this` isn't callable in the `static` method, how can I do this so?

Comment: You mean... Trace::info()?

Comment: So that helped you then? Your question is answered?

Comment: Nope, I can't call `$this->` in static method so I can't extends it

Comment: But you shouldn't use it as a member variable in your class, because it **is** a static thing... so instead of doing $this->_trace->info(), do Trace::info(), and make info a static function!

Comment: First of all, your code above fails. You can't  declare `private` and `public` outside a class declaration. I think it's only a distraction in writing question, but please correct it.

Comment: Okay but `Trace::info()` isn't a static method so I can't perform this operation. @fusion3k I correct it, thanks.

Comment: Try `self::$_trace` instead of `$this->_trace`. I'm not sure if it will work, since I can never remember if static functions call __construct.

Comment: Static functions don't call `__construct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want a class that will own an instance of Trace and will have static methods. BTW, your class is not a singleton.

**Method 1: with static methods**

```
<?php

  include "trace.php";

  class Test 
  {

      private static $_trace;

      public static function info()
      {
          self::getTraceInstance()->info();
      }

      private static getTraceInstance()
      {
          if (!isset(self::$trace)) {
              self::$trace = new Trace();
          }
          return self::$trace;
      }
  } 

  // usage:
  $test = new Test();
  $test->info();
```

**Method 2: make Test class a Singleton**

```
<?php

  include "trace.php";

  class Test 
  {

      private static $_instance;

      private $_trace;

      private function __construct()
      {
          $this->_trace = new Trace();
      }    

      public static function getInstance()
      {
          if (!isset(self::$_instance)) {
              self::$_instance = new static;
          }
          return self::$_instance;
      }   

      public function info()
      {
          $this->_trace->info();
      }          
  } 

  // usage:
  Test::getInstance()->info();
```

Comment: Okay you have understood correcly. I have few question: `1.` what does the method `getInstance` do? `2.` If I want pass some parameters in the `info` method I should do this: `Test::getInstance()->info($param1, $param2);`? Thanks

Comment: There is a bit problem, when I do this: `Test::getInstance()->info);` I get `Class Test not found` why?

Comment: @Sandokan maybe because your class name is not ‘Test’

Comment: @fusion3k nope is `Test` infact PhpStorm suggest also to use `Test` but when I ran my app I got the error.

Comment: PHPStorm does not know if you have loaded the class or it can be autoloaded. That problem is not related to your question.

Comment: If you want to use a class you must have it included, either manually or  autoloaded.

Comment: Okay I have fixed, so could you explain what does `getInstance` do exactly?

Comment: Returns the same `Test` instance on each call. If the instance is not created already, it creates it beforehand.

Comment: There is a problem in your code @gontrollez => `Access to undeclared static property: Test::$_instance`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103619/discussion-between-sandokan-and-gontrollez).

Comment: @gontrollez on this => `self::$_instance = new static;` I'm also in chat if you want more details for fix

Comment: are you sure you copied the ` private static $_instance;` line ?

Comment: I understand the problem, in particular when I do this: `Test::getInstance()->info();` no errors display but when I do this: `Test::getInstance()->info();` I get Argument 2 passed must be of the type array